# spatialization of triangular neighborhood networks

Tags: differential-geometry

Triangular Neighborhood Networks ($TNN$s) can be physically modeled by using *Knupferli* plastic elements. 
[image: Image number 1]

I have been able to construct simple but large $TNN$s using an icosahedral base model

[image: image nuber 2]

But I don't have an algorithm to three-dimensionally spatialize the torus.

Does anyone have ideas as to how this might be done?